# Safety stock calculations using Intermittent Bootstrap

Tags: forecasting, bootstrap, simulation

Together with fellow students, I’m working on an assignment to calculate safety stock levels in case of intermittent demand. We’re already able to simulate the demand like in the paper of Willemain, Smart, Schwarz (2004), but are now in question what is the best manner to approach the finalizing calculations of the safety stock per simulation. Currently we’re using a basic formula based on the maximum and average demand of every simulation but we’re wandering if this is a correct way. Do you have tips/suggestions on how to proceed?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The aim of Willemain et al.'s (2004) bootstrap is to estimate the entire probability distribution of total demand over the lead time. So if you want a safety stock that satisfies total demand in 95% of cases, just take the 95% quantile of this (bootstrap) estimated distribution.

Note that there are other definitions of service levels, many of which are orthogonal to total demand. One example would be line item fill rates, where you actually need the demand size of each separate order. An analysis of *total* demand will not be very helpful in this case.